# No Module Named pydispatch when using pyOpenGL

Tags: python, pyopengl

I have been attempting to follow a [**tutorial**](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/shader_1.xhtml) online and I have followed every single line and for some reason I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/OpenGLContextTest.py", line 2, in <module>
    from OpenGLContext import testingcontext
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openglcontext-2.2.0a2-py2.7.egg\OpenGLContext\testingcontext.py", line 10, in <module>
    from OpenGLContext import plugins, context, contextdefinition
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openglcontext-2.2.0a2-py2.7.egg\OpenGLContext\context.py", line 32, in <module>
    from OpenGLContext import visitor, texturecache,plugins
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openglcontext-2.2.0a2-py2.7.egg\OpenGLContext\visitor.py", line 3, in <module>
    from OpenGLContext.scenegraph import nodepath
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openglcontext-2.2.0a2-py2.7.egg\OpenGLContext\scenegraph\nodepath.py", line 3, in <module>
    from vrml.vrml97 import nodepath, nodetypes
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvrml97-2.3.0a2-py2.7.egg\vrml\vrml97\nodepath.py", line 4, in <module>
    from vrml import nodepath
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvrml97-2.3.0a2-py2.7.egg\vrml\nodepath.py", line 3, in <module>
    from vrml import node, weaklist
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvrml97-2.3.0a2-py2.7.egg\vrml\node.py", line 6, in <module>
    from vrml import field, fieldtypes, weaklist, weakkeydictfix
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvrml97-2.3.0a2-py2.7.egg\vrml\field.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pydispatch import dispatcher, robustapply
ImportError: No module named pydispatch
```

I have attempted searching on google for the chance that this tutorial may be broken or something, but I don't believe it is. I have pydispatch and have attempted to install it using `easy_install` yet nothing changes. Can someone please help me with this? I know the code is completely correct as after a while I copied and pasted everything to ensure that it wasn't my syntax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The instructions (apparently incorrectly) say to install `pydispatcher`. I had the same problem you did until I installed the module `PyDispatcher`. Confusingly, both exist.

Answer (score 4):

To clarify on @Phil's answer.

I saw:

`No module named pydispatch`

And so I did:

`sudo pip install pydispatch`

The install worked, but Scrapy still didn't work because we were supposed to:

`sudo pip install pydispatcher`

Answer (score 3):

You need to install PyDispatcher separately. Please take a look at the required packages for the tutorial to work along with the installation instructions here:

[PyOpenGL Introduction](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/shader_intro.xhtml)

Check particularly within the section named **Package Installation**

Comment: I already have it, that's what is troubling me. This is my message when attempting to install it: `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PyDispatcher in c:\ana
conda\lib\site-packages
Cleaning up...` and when using `easy_install`: `pydispatch 1.0.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pydispatch-1.0.3-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pydispatch
Finished processing dependencies for pydispatch`

Comment: can you try a simple pydispatch program from your python prompt. Simply try doing **import pydispatch** and check what you get?